# how to remove hide column option in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-grid

**ui-grid** in my demo .here is the api document
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro
I want to remove **hide option** from the columns .In each columns there is **"V"**  image and on click of that image it show **hide column** option.I want to remove that option .how it is possible

here is my code

```
 self.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableSorting: false

  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ye0HXTbKv6dDYTQ0DMyX?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you're after is here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu

You can remove the menu on each column header completely using:

```
enableColumnMenus: false
```

In your grid options as so:

```
self.gridOptions = {
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableRowSelection: true,
  multiSelect: false,
  enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
  enableSorting: false,
  enableColumnMenus: false
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide column menu by using colDef."enableColumnMenu":false

```
self.gridOptions.columnDefs=[ { field: 'name' },
                              { field: 'gender' },
                              { field: 'company', 
                                enableSorting: true,
                                enableColumnMenu :false }]
```